# I didn't put the lid on my slow cooker(crockpot) for first hour of beef stew. Will it still be safe to eat?

Tags: food-safety, crockpot

I didn't put the lid on the slow cooker (crockpot) properly for first hour of beef stew. It's on high now with the lid on, will it still be safe to eat?

Comment: You can always use a meat thermometer to ensure the beef is fully cooked if you have any concerns.

Answer (score 5):

It'll probably be fine. An hour isn't very long and I am willing to bet your food was getting hot anyway even if it wasn't getting as hot as quickly for the first hour.